# Count number of rows with specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm storing ratings for an item in a table called `ratings`.

`value` is an integer between 0 and 7 (the rating value).

As an example, let's say `showcase_id = 1` has 10 total ratings:

- 5 ratings are value = 7
- 2 ratings are value = 6
- 2 ratings are value = 5
- 1 rating is value = 4
- no ratings for values 0,1,2,3

Is there any efficient way I can select the total number of ratings for each specific value, the total number of ratings and the average rating from 1 single query?

e.g. the number of rows/count `WHERE value = 6` is 2. Would I need to do 7 separate subqueries?

```
SELECT AVG(value),COUNT(*),????
FROM ratings
WHERE showcase_id = :showcase_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to `count(distinct)`?

```
SELECT AVG(value), COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT value)
FROM ratings
WHERE showcase_id = :showcase_id;
```

EDIT:

If you want the total for each value, you can stuff this into one column, using a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt * value) / SUM(cnt) as average,
       SUM(cnt) as total_cnt,
       GROUP_CONCAT(value, '-', cnt ORDER BY VALUE) as values
FROM (SELECT value, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM ratings r
      WHERE showcase_id = :showcase_id
      GROUP BY value
     ) r;
```

Perhaps the subquery meets your needs as well.

Comment: That counts how many values are distinct, but I need to calculate how many ratings were given for each specific value

Comment: Your edit is giving an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'values
FROM (SELECT value, COUNT(*) as cnt, COUNT(DISTINCT value)
      FROM r' at line 3`

Comment: @frosty . . . Ooops, I left the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with group by?

```
SELECT AVG(value),COUNT(*), value
FROM ratings
WHERE showcase_id = :showcase_id
GROUP BY value;
```

EDIT (with the overall avg & totes):

```
select count(*) total_by_value, value, s1.full_avg, s1.full_total 
from ratings r,
(select avg(value) full_avg, count(*) full_total from ratings) s1
group by s1.full_avg, s1.full_total, value;
```

Comment: Well that counts how many for each specific value, but doesn't count the total number of ratings & the overall average. At least from what I see..

Comment: You also need to add `count(*)` to the `s1` subquery to get the total number of ratings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WITH ROLLUP` modifier to `GROUP BY` to get the counts and average for each value, as well as the totals for everything (if you group by multiple columns it will also create subtotals for each inner group).

```
SELECT value, AVG(value) AS avg, COUNT(*) as count
FROM ratings
WHERE showcase_id = 1
GROUP BY value WITH ROLLUP
```

This will produce a row for each value with its count, and then a row with `value = NULL` for that aggregates the entire result.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06f7a/1)